# Type alias to remove in array property

Tags: typescript

I use a 3rd party type that defines an array with specific shape like type:

```js
type ThirdPartyType = {
    a : string;
    b : string;
    c : string;
}[];
```

Note this is an array type of something thas has no type alias. Since it came from an external lib, I can't change it.

In my code, I'd like an array of items with the exact same shape, but without a specific property.

Let's say I want to remove the `A` field, I'd like to end up with something similar to :

```js
type WithoutA = {
    b : string;
    c : string;
}[];
```

But because the 3rd party actually contains a lot of fields, and is subject to change, I'd like to "remove" a field instead of "manually redeclaring" all others.

If I've had a type, I may have use the `Omit` utility type, but I have no such *item*'s type.

How can I do that ?

I tried this way :

```js
// From lib. can't change
type ThirdPartyType = {
    a : string;
    b : string;
    c : string;
}[];

// in my code
type ItemWithA =  { a : string };
type WithoutA <TItem extends ItemWithA[] > = Omit<TItem, 'a'>[];

const data : WithoutA<ThirdPartyType> = [
    {
        b : "foo",
        c : "bar"
    }
]
```

but the Omit applies to the array itself, not the inner type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the inner element type of a given array type using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).

`type ThirdPartyTypeItem = ThirdPartyType[number]`

So to get the type of the array without the element property `'a'`, it would be:

`Omit<ThirdPartyType[number], 'a'>[]`

Comment: Works fine ! Quite simple actually as soon as you know the syntax. Thanks

Comment: Hum actually, my actual 3rd party type may be undefined. `type ThirdPartyType = { ...}[] | undefined` (reduce my repro to a too simple code). Do you knwo how to handle this ?

Comment: If you want to create a derived type which you know for sure won't be undefined, it's `NonNullable<ThirdPartyType>`

Comment: It can be undefined

Comment: Ah, you want to modify it while keeping the end result potentially undefined... you could use NonNullable and then put the undefined back on at the end, like `Omit<NonNullable<ThirdPartyType>[number], 'a'>[] | undefined`

Comment: Ok I see. Tahnks you very much